# DeploymentUnitProcessingException

Tags: java, jboss-eap-7, jboss-developer-studio

when I try to deploy my project on my JBoss EAP 7.1
I get this error (stacktrace?):

```
16:13:07,986 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "test.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"test.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0041: Component class rest.RestResource for component RestResource has errors: 
WFLYJPA0033: Can't find a persistence unit named primary in deployment \"test.war\""},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".beanmanager"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".beanmanager]"
```

So, I have a DeploymentUnitProcessingException.
The console says that a persistence unit named primary cannot be found.
But I think that this is a lie because in my RestResource.java the unit name is
primary.

```
package rest;

import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/pair")
@Stateful
public class RestResource {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
    private EntityManager em;


    @POST
    public Pair writePair(Pair p) {
        em.persist(p);
        return p;
    }
}
```

The next claim of the console is that I dont have a beanmanager installed.
I searched for it and this should only be a problem if I dont have a beans.xml.
But I do have a src/META-INF/beans.xml and it can be created in a wizard of the IDE (Red Hat Developer Studio). Also, I read a beans.xml usually is no longer required.

Another thing that I found was
https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/issues/371

Here they suggest to rebuild the project with the command

```
mvn clean install -Pwildfly-managed
```

In my IDE I do it like this:

[image: executing the maven command]

That works just fine but the console output remains unchanged.

Have you had that problem before? Thank you for your help.

Edit 08.11.18
I added a screenshot of my folder structure, such that people can see the location of my persistence.xml and beans.xml
[image]

Edit 10.11.18
My beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans bean-discovery-mode="annotated" version="2.0"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"/>
```

is it correct?

Comment: You could start by placing persistence.xml in  /WEB-INF/classes/ + META-INF/persistence.xml for first issue,if not already done.For the second issue try moving your beans.xml inside WEB-INF/,that should help jboss find what it's looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not get many answers these days :( I added a screenshot of my directory structure. Now, the persistence.xml and the beans.xml should be at the right place. The console is still complaining about the same issue. Usually, after I made changes to my project I save, clean install the project and update it. I dont understand why the DeploymentUnitProcessingException is still there, even after your help :( Still, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the contents of your `beans.xml` file? The directory structure looks okay, but you may want to look at the created archive to ensure the `beans.xml` is in there.

Comment: Have you checked the archive,is the persistence.xml and beans.xml present in the correct folder in the archive?What is inside beans.xml?

Comment: I can see the beans.xml and the persistence.xml in the system explorer (is it the same as archive?) and in the project explorer of the IDE.